# Magereport is saying "No Magento installation found" for Magento sites

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magereport

I have several Magento websites that I have scanned with Magereport tool before but now I get the message `"No Magento installation found"` for **blastofffireworks.ca**

Any reason why your tool is not working anymore? All the sites I try to scan are Magento sites

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer, I work on magereport.com :)

Hi Gerhard, just so the solution to your question is here as well (I see you sent us a ticket about the site not working) for others to see:

The issue was that the firewall was blocking all countries except USA and Canada. We're scanning sites from IP's in the Netherlands and Belgium. So in order to get Magereport to work you have to allow those IP's in the firewall.

## Update

---

The following URL publishes which IPs are currently being used by magereport.com so if you whitelist those you should always be good: https://www.magereport.com/static/ips.txt

## Update May 2019

---

As of now Magereport will also indicate why a Magento installation could not be found. For example if a timeout or authorization issue is the cause it should mention this in the middle of the page:
[image]

Please note that if we *really* couldn't find a Magento install it will still say "No Magento install found". If you think this is wrong, please feel free to mail us at magereport@hypernode.com and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you visited the site while it was experiencing some downtime? My sites are scanning fine & yours did for me as well:

[image: blastofffireworks.ca]

They also include the following notice if the scan failed:

> Ai, we're not able to scan your webshop using the provided URL. Please try again, correct the URL or review your webserver accesslogs. If your firewall is blocking the requests, please whitelist our User-Agent "www.magereport.com". If you experience this issue on a Hypernode, please contact our support team.

Check with your host to see if they are blocking requests from www.magereport.com and `whitelist` if needed.

Comment: Can confirm. Site is also scanning correctly for me when I try that URL :)

Answer (score -1):

make sure you copy the complete url of website :http: //xxx.com from browser and paste in magereport, also you can scan in another tool here : magentary.com/magento-security-patch-tester